# React Native: Getting stuck while making a bundle (Server restart, New project) nothing helps

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, android-emulator

this issue is taking too much time. Please help me with this. I have been working on react native project for a while but a few days back I created a new react native project using
"npx react-native init projectname".
The project was created successfully and after I used the command "npx react-native run-android" to run it in the android emulator while being in the correct directory. The issue is every time I run it,  it gets stuck at some random step but mostly while bundling it. Once after 50 tries, it works for 2-3 tries but then it gets back and stucks in between.
What can be the issue? I have removed node-modules/re-created projects/re-installed android studio but nothing works even when I am using an external mobile device.

Anyone?[image]